# React Native endless stream of Socket SO_ERROR

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm working on an existing React Native project and in XCode log output I get an endless stream of the following errors

```
2019-01-09 12:15:49.005630+0000 App [13746:3543026] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C10.1:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2019-01-09 12:15:49.016640+0000 App [13746:3543026] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C10.2:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2019-01-09 12:15:49.017800+0000 App [13746:3543010] [] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C10] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
```

How could I go about figuring out where this error is coming from? It doesn't seem to be affecting the app, but I would like to understand the issue. I suspect it's not the app's JavaScript code, but one of the pods being used:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Firebase/Crash'
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @FrancoCoronel did you find a solution? :)

Answer (score 2):

1. To select XCode10 build system:
   In Xcode go to `File` -> `Project Settings` (or `Workspace settings`) -> `Build system`, in which change the `New Build System` to `Legacy Build System`.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9u4Ul.png)

2. Temporary fix: 
   `Edit Scheme` => `Run` => `Environment Variables` => Add `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE`:disable in the XCode.

Note: This works fine, but keep in mind that it also suppresses all NSLog output you may need for debugging.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i44P8.png)

Comment: If it suppresses the error messages, how do you know if the problem is solved?

Comment: Solution 1 is now deprecated then what to do?

Comment: #2 does nothing to resolve the issue.

Comment: Instead of suppressesing all logs, you might as well just not look at the console. That'll solve the issue too

Comment: this removed the logs from xcode and not giving output at react-native side.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same error

```
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-native": "^0.64.0",

Xcode: 13.1
iOS: 15.0
Node: 14.17.6
```

after investing a lot of time finally I got the solution and it worked for me. **I just *restarted* my machine.** I think the issue was with my network I was switched my network while the build was in progress.

Comment: You must've had something else going on because rebooting doesn't resolve anything.

Comment: Thank you! Been trying to figure out why these logs started showing up out of nowhere ~ restarting my machine fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

There is a thread on GitHub about that, it's **related to iOS 12+ an Xcode 10+**
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19573

I tried to change the buildSystem and it worked for me:

- Go to `File`, then `Project Settings` or `Workspace Settings`.
- Select `Legacy Build System` from the Build System dropdown.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't changing to legacy build system sort of just prevent an error message from appearing, rather than actually addressing the issue we are being warned of?

Comment: @DavidChopin Did you get a reply? Did you find a solution?

Comment: BTW, when running on an iPhone, do the iPhone and the Mac need to be on the same WiFi network?

Answer (score -9):

If you run your app on ios:
1. Go to ios/APP_NAME/Info.plist
2. Add these two entries to the Info.plist:

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>We'll show you things near you in the app.</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>We'll show you things near you in the app. With "always" access, we'll
    also send you notifications when you're near something interesting.</string>
```

Comment: This is not related to the issue in any way.